# How to deliberately slow down compilation?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compilation

There are a lot of questions asking how to speed up compilation of C++ code. I need to do the opposite.

I'm working with a software that monitors compiler invocation in order to do static code analysis. But if compiler process is closed too quickly, monitoring software can miss it. So I need to slow compilation down. I understand that's a terrible solution and hope it will be temporary.

I came up with two solutions:

- Disable parallel build, enable preprocessor and compiler listing generation. It works but requires a lot of mouse clicking
- Use compiler option to force inclusion of special header file that somehow slows compilation.

Unfortunately I couldn't come up with something simple to write and hard to compile at the same time. Using a lot of `#warning` seems to work but obviously clutters the output significantly.

I'm using Keil with armcc compiler, so I can use most of C++11 but maximum template recursion depth is just 63.

Preferably this should not produce any overhead for binary size or running time.

UPD: I'll try to clarify this a bit. *I know* that's a horrible idea, I know that this problem should be solved differently. I will try to solve it differently but I also want to explore this possibility.

Comment: You could always throw some expression templates at the compiler.  Those can quickly balloon causing compilation to take a very long time.

Comment: The static analysis tools I use are calling the compiler and don't depend on the speed of the (command line) compilation.  There are other static analysis tools that don't use a compiler.  What static analysis tools are you using?

Comment: Couldn't you just write a sleep program and run it in your Makefile or equivalent?

Comment: @NathanOliver can you provide a quick example?

Comment: @Broman that's an interesing idea! I'll try this one.

Comment: Maybe some low level keyboard hook in Windows to trigger on your compilator key shortcut, then start benchmarking from there... still, it is a bloody PC so I don't see what you'll be measuring. How fast your compiler is running while other programs are also running.

Comment: Not an answer, but I have to share that. Couple of days back I ran my compilation as usual, and instead of completing in 10 seconds, it kept going and going and going. Killed everything, cleaned all build artifacts, started full rebuild. Same thing. No major code changes, no toolchain change, What The Heck??? Several gray hairs later: I do have `#include <new>` in my code. I did some comparison between new and old versions of the program by processing huge data. Output files were called `old` and `new`, 10Gs worth of data. Current path was in the `-I` rules. May be you can relate? :)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "PVS Studio". It has no built-in integration into my IDE so I'm already inventing something abnormal.

Comment: If this software monitoring the compiler is something you are inventing, then simply replace the compile command with a command that first invokes the compiler and then indicates that the compiler was invoked and has finished. E.g., it could write a log message or send a network message. Then look for that indication instead of looking for the compiler process.

Comment: At my shop, we use Coverity and Parasoft; both of which we run command line through batch file (not connected to an IDE since people use different IDEs).

Comment: @Amomum, this is the epitome of XY questions.  Slowing down the compilation is a poor approach to triggering static analysis, and in all likelihood it would not work completely or reliably.  If you want static analysis then either integrate it directly into the build system or set it up as a separate concern.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I'm aware of that. I consider this only as temporary solution.

Comment: @Broman i'm afraid it won't produce desired effect; compiler processes still will exit quickly, they just be separated by a pause from said sleep program.

Comment: Under Unix/Linux, I might try `#include` on a file that's actually a named pipe, with a sending process on the other end that trickles the header content out over a period of several seconds..

Comment: You seem to be asking the wrong question. If your question was strictly "what C++ code would take a really long time to compile without producing binary output", ok. But that is not what you need or want it seems. What you really want is a solution to notice compiler invokation (down voted).

Comment: I do not think it's a good idea. Just try to dump the commands out of your IDE instead (e.g., something similar to what `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILER_COMMANDS=true` is doing.

Comment: Could you not just like, log it?

Comment: I remember reading, many years ago, about a BASIC command `WHOA`, that was a warning to the interpreter that the following code was tricky, and it should be extra careful when executing it. (That article also talked about a `COMEFROM` command, the inverse of `GOTO`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solution will be slow enough =), something like @NathanOliver propose.
Its compile time table sine I use. It requires extra space, but you can tune it a little (table size and sine accuracy are template parameters of "staticSinus" function, hope you`ll find your best).
https://godbolt.org/z/DYZDF5

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work well. I can even adjust slowing down by changing table size and sine accuracy :) The only drawback is that it uses a lot of space but that's not very important, I don't actually need to link this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do anything of the sort. Here are some solutions, of varying degree of kludginess:

1. Ideal solution: invoke the code **analysis** from the Makefile.
2. Replace the compiler with an e.g. Python script that forwards the command-line to the compiler, then triggers the **analysis** tool.
3. **Monitor** `make` instead of the compiler - it tends to live longer.
4. Have a tiny wrapper script maintain a reference count in shared memory, and when the reference count is initially incremented, the wrapper should go to sleep for "long enough" after the compiler has finished. **Monitor** that script.

In a nutshell: the monitoring tool shouldn't be monitoring anything. The code analysis should be invoked from the build tool, i.e. given in the `Makefile`. If generating the `Makefile` by hand is too cumbersome, use `cmake` with `ninja`, or `xmake` with no dependencies. You can also generate whatever "project" file the IDE needs to make working on the project easier. But make something else than Keil-specific stuff be the source of truth for the project: it'll make everything go easy from then on.

Comment: Your answer sounds very reasonable but will require a lot of work from my side. First things first - I don't use make. Second - I can't trigger analysis on the single file, analysis tool needs compiler flags and preprocessed file. Monitoring compiler invocations is the only avalaible "out of the box" way of doing that. Theoretically, I can create intermediete file for analysis tool but it's not documented at all. So I want a simple temporary solution while maintainers of the analysis tool will make proper integration to my IDE.

Comment: @Amomum, why cannot you replace a compiler binary with a wrapper script that would dump all the command line options into a file?

Comment: @Amomum Then wrapping the compiler in 5-line Python script and sleeping on the first (or last!) compiler invokation is your solution :)

Comment: @KubaOber monitoring software is beyond my control; i can only guess that it looks for a processes with a specific name. What good will it do to make a script that will sleep only python process and then invoke compiler with the same speed as before?

Comment: @SK-logic because I don't want to mess with static analysis tool file format. Slowing compilation down was an actual advice from tech. support :)

Comment: You can put the folder of a script with compiler’s name in the `PATH` before the compiler’s folder, so that the build system picks up the script. It can be .bat, .py, whatever. The script calls the compiler in the correct folder, and then sleeps. What you could also do is to see if file locking could be exploited to make the compiler itself block on access to a sentinel source file. If we go for baroque: put the sources on a Samba share on a minimal Linux VM running on your system, and limit the virtual network bandwidth. File padding = delay :) I’m kidding.